Does loop show up temporaily when connecting 2 working switches in STP(802.1d)?
I am learning CCNA. I can understand the STP (802.1d) port roles and states.
I wonder if the network (they have already been working) would be in loop within a very small moment after simultaneously plugging a cable into the 2 ports showed as image below (assuming Switch0 is the root brige).

As far as I know, the two ports should first transfer from disabled to blocking. As no BPDU are received, after the MaxAge time they would think they are not connect to the root, then think themselves as designated port and transfer to Listening state. After 2 forward delays, they come to the forwarding state at the same time. But when they begin sending BPDU, Switch2 and Switch1 would know they are connected to root bridge, and the newly connected 2 ports will respectively become a designated port and a blocked(alternative) port.
So is my interpretation correct? And if it's right, would it cause temporal loop in the network?

802.1D STP is long outdated and obsolete. Current STP variants are RSTP (802.1w) and MSTP (802.1s), incorporated into IEEE 802.1Q. Are you really asking about 802.1D?

Yes. I am learning CCNA and I know 802.1D STP is outdated. But I want a better understanding of it. As for PVST+ on packet tracer, the difference from 802.1D STP is only on VLAN. If I leave the VLAN to be default, which is one, the behavior should not be different from 802.1D STP

The more modern STP variants differ from 802.1D in the port role model, and that is exactly what your question is about - I'm not sure whether anyone here wants to provide an outdated answer, or if your question is really on topic here...

I wonder if my question is helpful to better understand modern STP. If it's not, I would be willing/glad to delete my question.

I got it. I made a mistake. At listening state, BPDU is allowed to be forwarded (according to Std 802.1D, 1998 Part 3 page 84 section 8.4.2), so my interpretation is not correct. I am wondering if I need to delete my question or leave it here as it maybe help others have similar confusion.

You can provide an answer yourself and then accept it (24h later I think) for your question to be helpful for others. Otherwise it'll stay unanswered and keep popping up here forever.

There's a mistake in the interpretation said in the question. At listening state, though the port is not able to forward user data, it is able to send BPDU, as IEEE Std 802.1D 1998 Part 3 page 84 section 8.4.2 said:

BPDUs received shall be processed as required by the Spanning Tree
Algorithm and Protocol. BPDUs can be submitted for transmission.

I found a YouTube video summarized the STP states and their abilities in a table. I clipped it down to below (with slightly modification which I thought such that it could be clearer)




Port States
Receiving BPDUs
Sending BPDUs
Learn MAC addresses
Forward User Data




Disabled
No
No
No
No


Blocking
Yes
No
No
No


Listening
Yes
Yes
No
No


Learning
Yes
Yes
Yes
No


Forwarding
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes





As Zac said, 802.1d is outdated. It just for other learners like me to better understand the legacy STP process.
In RSTP+, the discarding state, also can send BPDUs, although they can't forward user data. I think that's why switches can communicate with each other even the two ports are in alternate role.
